# I used GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in my .env file and packge.json also but it was not hiding my code after deployment i used vercel.com to deploy it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web, webpack

I can not hide my code from user in the browser inspector and after applying GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false in .env file but still it does not hide my code after deployment , and I use vercel to deploy my projects

***strong text***[image]